# How to fix: Unable to connect to www.google.com:443 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to www.google.com:443 (No route to host)

Tags: php, recaptcha, zend-framework3

I'm trying to use recaptcha in Zend Framework 3. When I submit the form, I get the error:

> Unable to connect to www.google.com:443 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to www.google.com:443 (No route to host)

My code works with test keys on lockalhost under Windows. But don't work on my linux hosting.

### MyForm.php

```
<?php
use Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class MyForm extends Form {
  private const SITE_KEY = '';
  private const SECRET_KEY = '';
  public function __construct($name = null) {
    // Add some elements
    parent::__construct('new_password');
    $captcha = new Element\Captcha('captcha');
    $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha();
    $recaptcha->setSiteKey(self::SITE_KEY);
    $recaptcha->setSecretKey(self::SECRET_KEY);
    $captcha->setCaptcha($recaptcha);
    $captcha->setLabel('Please verify you are human');
    $this->add($captcha);
    // Add submit
  }
}
?>
```

### my_template.phtml

```
<?php 
  $captcha = $form->get('captcha'); ?>
  <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
  <div>
    <?= $this->formLabel($captcha) ?>
    <?= $this->formElement($captcha) ?>
    <?= $this->formElementErrors()->render($captcha) ?>
  </div>
  <?php
    echo $this->formSubmit($submit);
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
   ?>
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please make sure the openssl extension is enabled in PHP.ini - socket 443 means you're attempting to make a secure connection. It will fail without SSL enabled.

Comment: That hosting does not provide terminal access. `echo phpinfo();` looks like that [phpinfo img](http://prntscr.com/mjz1as)

Comment: Is the server behind a proxy?